# When using @Qualifier, [Dagger/MissingBinding] int[] cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I've written the code below to get me an `IntArray` and it works fine when I'm not annotating it with `@Qualifer`, but when I do, I get the error message below:

My module file (both annotation and modules are in same file)

```kotlin
@Qualifier
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER, AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class ItemColorArray

@Module
class ModuleGeneral {
    @Provides
    @ItemColorArray
    fun provideItemColorArray(context: Context): IntArray {
        return context.resources.getIntArray(R.array.timetableItems)
    }
}
```

Usage inside a dialogFragment:

```kotlin
@Inject
@ItemColorArray
lateinit var itemColorArray: IntArray
```

Error message:

```
{fileAddress}\di\AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] int[] cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      int[] is injected at
          {packageName}.ui.dialogs.addSubject.AddSubjectDialog.itemColorArray
```

Again, everything works fine when I'm not using any `@Qualifier`. Using the `@Named("xxx")` qualifier  produces the same error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add your module to your component?

Comment: You might need to use `@field:ItemColorArray`, but it should be fixed with the latest version. What version are you using? Try updating

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Updating to v2.27 (from 2.24) fixed the problem. Please write it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualifiers with Kotlin on fields were fixed / improved with [Dagger version 2.25](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.25.2).

Make sure to use the latest version and it should work.

---

Alternatively you can use `@field:MyQualifier` so that previous versions can pick it up.